# A brief explainer request

Tags: javascript

I recently worked through the code below. While I understand the logic of most of it, the one detail I did not understand is why these lines:

```
var list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
var totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
var total = 0;
list.innerHTML = '';
totalBox.textContent = '';
```

I assume '.output ul' is a CSS element that focuses the code on `var products`. Is this right? 
`list.innerhtml = '';`?

```
var list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
var totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
var total = 0;
list.innerHTML = '';
totalBox.textContent = '';

var products = ['Underpants:6.99',
 'Socks:5.99',
 'T-shirt:14.99',
 'Trousers:31.99',
 'Shoes:23.99'];

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
 var subArray = products[i].split(':');
 var name = subArray[0];
 var price = Number(subArray[1]);
 total += price;
 itemText = name + ' — $' + price;

 var listItem = document.createElement('li');
 listItem.textContent = itemText;
 list.appendChild(listItem);
}

totalBox.textContent = 'Total: $' + total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking and/or what additional information is required. Do you just not know what `innerHTML` or `textContent` are?

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('.output ul');` would return all the elements with the tag `ul` that have at-least 1 parent with the class `output`. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Using `document.querySelector` will only return the first item from that list. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

`list.innerHTML = '';` clears all of the contents of the element (html + text)
`totalBox.textContent = '';` does exactly the same thing (even though it says `textContent`)

The difference between `innerHTML` and `textContent` is that when you read them, one will return all of the contents of the element, whereas the other on will only return the text.

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
var totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
var total = 0;
list.innerHTML = '';
totalBox.textContent = '';
```

```html
<div class="output">
  <ul>I will get cleared up</ul>
  <ul>I will remain intact</ul>
</div>

<div class="output">
  <div>
    <p>I will get cleared up</p>
    <p>I will remain intact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check MDN's documentation for css selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
var totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
```

From mozilla docs,

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned [- QuerySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

What that basically means is, it selects the HTML DOM element that matches the conditions, in your case it will select the first element that has at least one parent with the CSS class `output` and is of type `ul` i.e.,

Elements like ->

```html
<div class="output">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

> NOTE:- The matching class has to be on one of the ul's parent element. If it it's not on the parent element but is present on the ul itself, then it will not be selected.

Ex:->

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
console.log(list);
```

```html
    <div>
    <ul class="output">
    </ul>
    </div>
```

No one element is selected in this case.

And gives you reference to this element to manipulate it.

Take a look at the different types of selectors also, here  [- CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: That's still incorrect, `<ul class="output"></ul>` cannot get selected by `document.querySelector('.output ul')`

Comment: Yes, It was wrong, it will only select if the parent has the specified class. I have edited it. The confusion came from most of the times that I have used querySelector has been for div, which most of the times had the same class as the parent. Thanks!